# is there any simple way to do an opposite of else at the end of an if-else chain?

Tags: c++

Is there a simpler generic way to have a set of code run that uses the values set in an if-else chain, only if one of the if-else conditions was true? I'd sort of like to close the chain with a statement that means the opposite of else... like "if", "else", "ok one of those was true now do this."

Generically an obvious implementation is this:

```
bool somethingWasTrue = true;
if( x )
    z = 0;
else if( y )
    z = ResultOfSomething();
else
    somethingWasTrue = false;

if( somethingWasTrue )
{
    // code that uses z
}
```

The best potential solution i can come up with is using an optional z, then instead of if( somethingWasTrue ) having if( z )

Comment: For this limited example, just put `return` after the `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with your "obvious implementation".  I think it's most legible.

And it's not really wasteful. Both g++ and clang++ eliminate the `bool` at even the -O1 optimization level: [see here](https://godbolt.org/g/ZmzDEP).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need that `somethingWasTrue` variable at all. Use breakable block:

```
do {
  if( x )
    z = 0;
  else if( y )
    z = ResultOfSomething();
  else
    break;

  // code that uses z
} while(false);
```

Comment: If your intent is `goto`, then why don't you use it? Why this `do/break/while (false)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can `break` out of a loop to early terminate the `else`, and continue processing otherwise.

```
do {
    if( x )
        z = 0;
    else if( y )
        z = ResultOfSomething();
    else
        break;

    // code that uses z
} while( 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
bool somethingWasTrue = true;
if( x )
    z = 0;
else if( y )
    z = ResultOfSomething();
else
    // code that uses z
```

Since you are wanting a "default" selection to fire if the first two "ifs" are false, just put an "else" on the end.

Comment: Not quite, OP wants to set `somethingWasTrue` to false if they reach the final `else` (i.e. they don't want to run "code that uses z" if the last else is hit).

Answer (score 0):

How about creating sub function:

```
void foo(int z)
{
    // code that uses z
}
```

And then

```
if (x)
    foo(0);
else if( y )
    foo(ResultOfSomething());
```